# Is a differentiable multivariable function with continuous derivatives on analytic paths continuously differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be an everywhere differentiable function; and continuously differentiable when restricted to any analytic path.

Is then $f$ continuously differentiable?
I would bet on no, but I failed to construct a counter-example in a reasonable time.
But maybe I am overthinking, and there should be a way to show the continuous differentiability?

This problem came to me from my research: I found myself in a company of a functional, which is smooth outside of some codimension 1 piecewise-analytic set. I was able to show that over this set the functional is differentiable. It was also clear that its restriction to any analytic path was nice. So I started wondering whether I can rely on that my functional friend is $C^1$.

Comment: Hmm. Gut says yes. Problem is different from asking for directionally differentiable at every point (which does have a counter example)

Comment: The following is a theorem: "a function, defined on an open set, is continuously differentiable ($p$ times) if and only if all its partial derivatives (up to $p$th order) are continuous."

Comment: @William, I know this, but, unfortunately, I do not know how to show continuity of partial derivatives from the fact that the restriction of the differential of $f$ to each analytic path is continuous (and I actually suspect that there should be counterexamples).

Comment: It is a corollary: the partial derivatives are the derivatives of $f$ restricted to lines which are analytical paths!

Comment: @William, I believe that this is different: to make use the theorem you quoted, you need to ensure that partial derivatives are continuous as functions on $\mathbb R^n$. Even if I know that the restrictions of partial derivatives to analytic paths are continuous, I do not know how to show from this that they are continuous on open sets. But the information I have (on the restriction of the differential) is even weaker than that.

Comment: The theorem is actually local: a necessary and sufficient condition for $f:B(x; r) \to \mathbf{R}^q$ to be ($p$ times) continuously differentiable at $x$ is that (the $(p-1)$th derivate of) $f$ be continuous on the ball with the ($p$th) derivative existing on the ball and the ($p$th) derivative be continuous at $x.$

Comment: @William, I know this, but unfortunately, I do not know how to show even locally that a multivariable function is continuous, if its restriction to any analytic path is continuous. I would be glad if you can help with it! I even created a separate question asking for this (in smooth and in analytic settings): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4364494/discontinuous-function-with-continuous-restriction-to-any-smooth-curve
But note that here the condition is even weaker than this.

Comment: I think the question you asked is not what you wanted to ask. You assumed "Let $f:\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}$ be an everywhere differentiable function; and continuously differentiable when restricted to any analytic path." This implies $f$ has continuous partial derivatives (everywhere) so the theorems I stated apply!

Comment: @William, would you show how this implies? Unfortunately, I do not see a proof.

Comment: @William, How would you show, for instance, that $\partial f/\partial x$ is continuous over any open set? Or, e.g., along the path $x=0$?

Comment: The partial derivatives of $f$ at a point $p$ are the derivatives of the composition $f(p + t v)$ where $v$ is one of the canonical vectors in $\mathbf{R}^n.$ Note that the curve $t \mapsto p + tv$ is analytic (for it is a polynomial). And because $f$ has continuous partial derivatives everywhere on $\mathbf{R}^n,$ it is continuously differentiable everywhere.

Comment: @William, I believe that this only shows, e.g., the continuity of $\partial f/\partial x$ over horizontal lines, but not their continuity on any open set in $\mathbb R^n$. And, unfortunately, it is not enough to apply the theorem you quoted.

Comment: Actually, it seems to me that, e.g., the function
$$f(x, y)=e^{-1/x^2}\ln(y^2+e^{-2/x^2})$$
(extended by zero to $x=0$) does the job of a counterexample. But I still need to verify it thoroughly, which I will do later.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem.** Let $U$ be an open set of $\mathbf{R}^d$ and $f:U \to \mathbf{R}.$ In order for $f$ to be continuously differentiable on $U,$ it is necessary and sufficient that each of the partial derivatives of $f$ exist and be continuous on $U.$

*Proof.* Let $h \in \mathbf{R}^d.$ Write $h^0 = 0$ and $h^j = (h_1, \ldots, h_j, 0, \ldots, 0),$ so that $h^d = h.$ Obviously, the only candidate that can be derivative of $f$ is the linear function
$$
k \mapsto \nabla f(p) \cdot k = \sum_{j = 1}^d \partial_j f(p) \cdot k_j.
$$
We are going to show that this function actually satisfies the definition of derivative.
Then, we have to show that
$$
f(p + h) - f(p) - \sum_{j = 1}^d \partial_j f(p) \cdot h_j = \sum_{j = 1}^d \Big( f(p+h^j)-f(p+h^{j-1}) - \partial_j f(p) \cdot h_j \Big)
$$
is a $o(h)$ function (this will prove that the derivative of $f$ is given by the partial derivatives, as expected, and since the latter are continuous functions, by hypothesis, the former is also continuous).

By the mean value theorem and *since the partial derivatives exists everywhere on $U$*,
$$
f(p + h^j) - f(p+h^{j-1}) = \partial_j f(p+h^{j-1}) h_j.
$$
Therefore,
$$
f(p + h) - f(p) - \sum_{j = 1}^d \partial_j f(p) \cdot h_j = \sum_{j = 1}^d \Big( \partial_j f(p + h^{j-1}) - \partial_j f(p) \Big) h_j
$$
By continuity of the partial derivatives, $\partial_j f(p + h^{j-1}) - \partial_j f(p) = o(1)$ as $h \to 0.$ (Note that the term corresponding to $j = 1$ actually vanish, so we don't need continuity of $\partial_1 f.$) Whence,
$$
f(p + h) - f(p) - \sum_{j = 1}^d \partial_j f(p) \cdot h_j = \sum_{j = 1}^d o(1) h_j = o(h). \square
$$

**Returning to your exercise...** So, there you have it, if a function has continuous partial derivatives everywhere (as in your hypothesis), it is differentiable everywhere (and since the derivative as continuous entries, it is continuously differentiable everywhere).

Comment: Dear William, thanks a lot for writing this and for your willingness to help! But as we discussed in the comments, unfotunately, I do not see how one can extract the continuity of the partial derivatives from the hypothesis of my problem. My hypothesis gives, e.g., the continuity of $\partial f/\partial x$ along horizontal lines, but does not give (at least straightforwardly) its continuity on any open set.

Comment: Finally I understand your concern. I wouldn't know about analytic paths but if you only want continuous paths, then yes, the derivative will be continuous. The proof is the same as for continuity. In other words, if $f$ is continuous on every continuous path converging to some point then the function is continuous on that point. To prove this, you would proceed by contradiction, constructing a sequence converging to the point of discontinuity and then joining these sequences by straight lines; this gives a continuous path where the function is discontinuous.

Comment: @Taras I suspect I should have tagged you in my previous comment for you to receive the notification. Let me know if that helps; I suspect one can glue differentiable points in the space (so that one gets a differentiable curve joining them) but I strongly suspect that analytically joining them is not possible.

Comment: William, your comment is pretty clear, thanks, and it shows the caveat of the problem. 
The whole problem is about understanding if the continuity can be somehow extracted just from restrictions to analytic paths. 
And I think that I have now a good candidate for a counterexample: see my last comment to the question.

Comment: William, by the way, if you actually know how in your construction of a continuous path to ensure that it is smooth at the limit point, then I will be very glad if you let me know! Post it there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4364494/discontinuous-function-with-continuous-restriction-to-any-smooth-curve
This I still do not have an idea how to do

Comment: I do not know why, but I could not tag you in the previous comments, @William

Comment: @Taras If I reply yo your main thread, you get a notification automatically, same if you reply to my answer (I get automatic notification). But for you to get a notification from my answer, I have to tag you; same, for me to get a notification from your main thread, you have to tag me.